# Access default docker compose network during build time?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, next.js

How can i access the default docker compose network during build time with docker compose?

I can't generate my next js app because i don't have access to the network of my backend during build time.

A simplified version of my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  graph:
    container_name: graph
    image: graph-image
    env_file:
      - ./graph/.env.prod
    build: ./graph

  web:
    container_name: web
    image: web-image
    env_file:
      - ./web/.env.prod
    build: 
      context: ./web
      network: default
    depends_on:
      - graph
```

The error i get during build time:
ApolloError: request to http://graph:4000/graphql failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND graph

I know that http://graph:4000/graphql is accessible on the default docker compose network

Comment: An image build runs without most of the other Compose settings, and mechanically it can't connect to the other service because there's no way to connect them to the same network.  Can you extract a static GraphQL schema from your service and add that to your source tree, rather than using an introspection query?

Comment: I need data for static generation and not type information, so I don’t think that I can extract what I need without the service running. My workaround, which I’m not a big fan of, will be to extract the data I need directly from the db I my next.js backend. I only need to read one table so I think it will be fine